# Get the sum of earnings of all payments for a user?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**User** → has many → **Book** → has many → **Order** → has many  **Payment**

in Book Model:

```php
public function payments()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Payment::class, Order::class);
}
```

Orders table

```php
 Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('book_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('amount');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('books');
        });
```

Payments migration:

```php
 Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
            $table->string('payment_method');
            $table->unsignedInteger('author_earning');

            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
        });
    }
```

My problem: **I want to list all users with the sum of `author_earning` for all payments that belongs to their books**.
I have tried to do something like:

```
$users = User::with(['books.payments' => function ($query) {
            $query->sum('instructor_earning');
        }])
        ->whereHas('books.payments')
        ->get();
```

But, no luck. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you use **with many relations**, the closure need to get the eloquent builder columns at least including the foreign_key, eloquent use this foreign_key to make the nested collection.

However, **sum** will return **a number**, not eloquent columns;

so if you sum the payment's author_earning for each book, you can use accessor,

Do it like this,
In Book model:

```php
protected $appends = ['author_earning'];

public function getAuthorEarningAttribute()
{
    $sum = Book::where('books.id', $this->id)
        ->join('orders', 'orders.book_id', '=', 'books.id')
        ->join('payments', 'payments.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
        ->groupBy('books.id')
        ->selectRaw('books.id, SUM(payments.amount) AS sum')
        ->first()->sum;
    return $sum;
}
```

So when you with books' payments like this:

```php
$users = User::with(['books.payments'])
        ->whereHas('books.payments')
        ->get()->toJson();
```

you will get the datas like this:

```
[{"id":1,
  "username":"Tom",
  "books":[{
    "id":1,
    "title": "Tom and Jerry",
    "author_earning": 18,
    "orders": [{
      "id":1,
      "number": "FA00000001"
      "payments": [{"id":1,"author_earning":15},{"id":2,"author_earning": 3}]
    },{
    "id":2,
    "title": "Dragon Ball",
    "author_earning": 2,
    "orders": [{
      "id":2,
      "number": "FA00000002"
      "payments": [{"id":1,"author_earning":2}]        
    }]
  }]
}]
```